# Same Query More Variables Way Different Speed Results

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand why my query has failed when changing variable size.

This query runs in less than one second:

```
SELECT 
s1.biz_name,s1.biz_info,s1.e_address,s1.e_city,s1.e_state,s1.e_postal,s1.e_zip_full,s1.loc_lat_centroid,s1.loc_long_centroid,s1.biz_phone,s1.biz_phone_ext,s1.biz_fax,s1.biz_email,s1.web_url,s2.upc AS upc2,s2.retailprice AS
retailprice2,s2.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales2, 
s2.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly2, 
s2.todaydate AS todaydate2,s2.datetimesql AS datetimesql2, 
s2.shelfposition AS shelfposition2,s2.reg_sale AS reg_sale2, 
s2.representative AS representative2,s2.notes AS notes2,s3.upc AS 
upc3,s3.retailprice AS retailprice3,s3.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales3, 
s3.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly3,s3.todaydate AS todaydate3, 
s3.datetimesql AS datetimesql3,s3.shelfposition AS shelfposition3, 
s3.reg_sale AS reg_sale3,s3.representative AS representative3,s3.notes AS notes3 
,s4.upc AS upc4,s4.retailprice AS retailprice4,s4.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales4, 
s4.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly4,s4.todaydate AS todaydate4, 
s4.datetimesql AS datetimesql4,s4.shelfposition AS shelfposition4, 
s4.reg_sale AS reg_sale4,s4.representative AS representative4,s4.notes AS notes4 
,s5.upc AS upc5,s5.retailprice AS retailprice5,s5.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales5, 
s5.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly5,s5.todaydate AS todaydate5, 
s5.datetimesql AS datetimesql5,s5.shelfposition AS shelfposition5, 
s5.reg_sale AS reg_sale5,s5.representative AS representative5,s5.notes AS notes5 
FROM   allstores AS s1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s2 
         ON s1.e_address = s2.e_address 
            AND s2.upc = '650637119004' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s3 
         ON s1.e_address = s3.e_address 
            AND s3.upc = '650637119011' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s4 
         ON s1.e_address = s4.e_address 
            AND s4.upc = '650637374007' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s5 
         ON s1.e_address = s5.e_address 
            AND s5.upc = '650637374014' 
WHERE  s2.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s3.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s4.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s5.e_address IS NOT NULL
```

This query never completes:

```
SELECT 
s1.biz_name,s1.biz_info,s1.e_address,s1.e_city,s1.e_state,s1.e_postal,s1.e_zip_full,s1.loc_lat_centroid,s1.loc_long_centroid,s1.biz_phone,s1.biz_phone_ext,s1.biz_fax,s1.biz_email,s1.web_url,s2.upc AS upc2,s2.retailprice AS
retailprice2,s2.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales2, 
s2.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly2, 
s2.todaydate AS todaydate2,s2.datetimesql AS datetimesql2, 
s2.shelfposition AS shelfposition2,s2.reg_sale AS reg_sale2, 
s2.representative AS representative2,s2.notes AS notes2,s3.upc AS 
upc3,s3.retailprice AS retailprice3,s3.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales3, 
s3.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly3,s3.todaydate AS todaydate3, 
s3.datetimesql AS datetimesql3,s3.shelfposition AS shelfposition3, 
s3.reg_sale AS reg_sale3,s3.representative AS representative3,s3.notes AS notes3 
,s4.upc AS upc4,s4.retailprice AS retailprice4,s4.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales4, 
s4.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly4,s4.todaydate AS todaydate4, 
s4.datetimesql AS datetimesql4,s4.shelfposition AS shelfposition4, 
s4.reg_sale AS reg_sale4,s4.representative AS representative4,s4.notes AS notes4 
,s5.upc AS upc5,s5.retailprice AS retailprice5,s5.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales5, 
s5.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly5,s5.todaydate AS todaydate5, 
s5.datetimesql AS datetimesql5,s5.shelfposition AS shelfposition5, 
s5.reg_sale AS reg_sale5,s5.representative AS representative5,s5.notes AS notes5 
,s6.upc AS upc6,s6.retailprice AS retailprice6,s6.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales6, 
s6.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly6,s6.todaydate AS todaydate6, 
s6.datetimesql AS datetimesql6,s6.shelfposition AS shelfposition6, 
s6.reg_sale AS reg_sale6,s6.representative AS representative6,s6.notes AS notes6 
,s7.upc AS upc7,s7.retailprice AS retailprice7,s7.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales7, 
s7.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly7,s7.todaydate AS todaydate7, 
s7.datetimesql AS datetimesql7,s7.shelfposition AS shelfposition7, 
s7.reg_sale AS reg_sale7,s7.representative AS representative7,s7.notes AS notes7 
,s8.upc AS upc8,s8.retailprice AS retailprice8,s8.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales8, 
s8.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly8,s8.todaydate AS todaydate8, 
s8.datetimesql AS datetimesql8,s8.shelfposition AS shelfposition8, 
s8.reg_sale AS reg_sale8,s8.representative AS representative8,s8.notes AS notes8 
,s9.upc AS upc9,s9.retailprice AS retailprice9,s9.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales9, 
s9.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly9,s9.todaydate AS todaydate9, 
s9.datetimesql AS datetimesql9,s9.shelfposition AS shelfposition9, 
s9.reg_sale AS reg_sale9,s9.representative AS representative9,s9.notes AS notes9 
,s10.upc AS upc10,s10.retailprice AS retailprice10, 
s10.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales10,s10.dollar_sales_ly AS 
dollar_sales_ly10,s10.todaydate AS todaydate10,s10.datetimesql AS 
datetimesql10,s10.shelfposition AS shelfposition10,s10.reg_sale AS reg_sale10, 
s10.representative AS representative10,s10.notes AS notes10,s11.upc AS 
upc11,s11.retailprice AS retailprice11,s11.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales11, 
s11.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly11,s11.todaydate AS 
todaydate11,s11.datetimesql AS datetimesql11, 
s11.shelfposition AS shelfposition11, 
s11.reg_sale AS reg_sale11,s11.representative AS representative11, 
s11.notes AS notes11,s12.upc AS upc12,s12.retailprice AS 
retailprice12,s12.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales12,s12.dollar_sales_ly AS 
dollar_sales_ly12,s12.todaydate AS todaydate12,s12.datetimesql AS 
datetimesql12,s12.shelfposition AS shelfposition12,s12.reg_sale AS reg_sale12, 
s12.representative AS representative12,s12.notes AS notes12,s13.upc AS 
upc13,s13.retailprice AS retailprice13,s13.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales13, 
s13.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly13,s13.todaydate AS 
todaydate13,s13.datetimesql AS datetimesql13, 
s13.shelfposition AS shelfposition13, 
s13.reg_sale AS reg_sale13,s13.representative AS representative13, 
s13.notes AS notes13,s14.upc AS upc14,s14.retailprice AS 
retailprice14,s14.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales14,s14.dollar_sales_ly AS 
dollar_sales_ly14,s14.todaydate AS todaydate14,s14.datetimesql AS 
datetimesql14,s14.shelfposition AS shelfposition14,s14.reg_sale AS reg_sale14, 
s14.representative AS representative14,s14.notes AS notes14,s15.upc AS 
upc15,s15.retailprice AS retailprice15,s15.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales15, 
s15.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly15,s15.todaydate AS 
todaydate15,s15.datetimesql AS datetimesql15, 
s15.shelfposition AS shelfposition15, 
s15.reg_sale AS reg_sale15,s15.representative AS representative15, 
s15.notes AS notes15,s16.upc AS upc16,s16.retailprice AS 
retailprice16,s16.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales16,s16.dollar_sales_ly AS 
dollar_sales_ly16,s16.todaydate AS todaydate16,s16.datetimesql AS 
datetimesql16,s16.shelfposition AS shelfposition16,s16.reg_sale AS reg_sale16, 
s16.representative AS representative16,s16.notes AS notes16,s17.upc AS 
upc17,s17.retailprice AS retailprice17,s17.dollar_sales AS dollar_sales17, 
s17.dollar_sales_ly AS dollar_sales_ly17,s17.todaydate AS 
todaydate17,s17.datetimesql AS datetimesql17, 
s17.shelfposition AS shelfposition17, 
s17.reg_sale AS reg_sale17,s17.representative AS representative17, 
s17.notes AS notes17 
FROM   allstores AS s1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s2 
         ON s1.e_address = s2.e_address 
            AND s2.upc = '075172039394' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s3 
         ON s1.e_address = s3.e_address 
            AND s3.upc = '075172071622' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s4 
         ON s1.e_address = s4.e_address 
            AND s4.upc = '075172071639' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s5 
         ON s1.e_address = s5.e_address 
            AND s5.upc = '075172071677' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s6 
         ON s1.e_address = s6.e_address 
            AND s6.upc = '075172071684' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s7 
         ON s1.e_address = s7.e_address 
            AND s7.upc = '075172071691' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s8 
         ON s1.e_address = s8.e_address 
            AND s8.upc = '075172079130' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s9 
         ON s1.e_address = s9.e_address 
            AND s9.upc = '075172079147' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s10 
         ON s1.e_address = s10.e_address 
            AND s10.upc = '075172079154' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s11 
         ON s1.e_address = s11.e_address 
            AND s11.upc = '075172079307' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s12 
         ON s1.e_address = s12.e_address 
            AND s12.upc = '075172079369' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s13 
         ON s1.e_address = s13.e_address 
            AND s13.upc = '075172079468' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s14 
         ON s1.e_address = s14.e_address 
            AND s14.upc = '075172079604' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s15 
         ON s1.e_address = s15.e_address 
            AND s15.upc = '075172079618' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s16 
         ON s1.e_address = s16.e_address 
            AND s16.upc = '075172079659' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN storecheckrecords AS s17 
         ON s1.e_address = s17.e_address 
            AND s17.upc = '075172079697' 
WHERE  s2.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s3.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s4.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s5.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s6.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s7.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s8.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s9.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s10.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s11.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s12.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s13.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s14.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s15.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s16.e_address IS NOT NULL 
        OR s17.e_address IS NOT NULL
```

e_address is indexed.

Can anyone shed some light on the possible issue(s)?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question and add some line breaks. You can highlight the whole thing and press ctl-k to reindent it as a code block.  The rest of us can edit, but honestly this is just too much work.

Comment: Can you format your queries in the question so they're not all one long line, and are actually readable?

Comment: Maybe if you edit the question so it's easier to see the difference between the queries, more could help. Currently they're both one long line that's not easy to read.

Comment: I think you need to go back to the drawing board on this one, or post a vastly simplified version of both queries.

Comment: I clicked on 'edit', but then I said "wow...nvm" :-\. @MrE I think you have too much free time ^^

Comment: Ran it through http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm but I don't think it'll help much

Comment: @MrE oh...I thought you formatted it with your "hand" :P

Comment: Do you have an index on `upc`? Or a compound index  on `(upc, e_address)`?

Answer (score 5):

Let me reformat that for you slightly to make the problem slightly more obvious:

```
....
FROM allStores AS s1
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s2 ON s1.e_address = s2.e_address AND s2.upc = '075172039394'
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s3 ON s1.e_address = s3.e_address AND s3.upc = '075172071622'
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s4 ON s1.e_address = s4.e_address AND s4.upc = '075172071639'
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s5 ON s1.e_address = s5.e_address AND s5.upc = '075172071677'
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s6 ON s1.e_address = s6.e_address AND s6.upc = '075172071684'
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s7 ON s1.e_address = s7.e_address AND s7.upc = '075172071691'
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s8 ON s1.e_address = s8.e_address AND s8.upc = '075172079130'
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s9 ON s1.e_address = s9.e_address AND s9.upc = '075172079147'
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s10 ON s1.e_address = s10.e_address AND s10.upc = '075172079154'
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s11 ON s1.e_address = s11.e_address AND s11.upc = '075172079307'
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s12 ON s1.e_address = s12.e_address AND s12.upc = '075172079369'
LEFT OUTER JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s13 ON s1.e_address = s13.e_address AND s13.upc = '075172079468' 
etc...
```

Holy smoke! That's a lot of joins! It's not that surprising that this runs slower and slower as you add more "variables". Every UPC you add to your query needs one more join.

I think you just want an `IN` expression. Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    s1.biz_name,
    s1.biz_info,
    s1.e_address,
    -- etc..
    s2.reg_sale, 
    s2.representative,
    s2.notes
FROM allStores AS s1
JOIN storeCheckRecords AS s2
ON s1.e_address = s2.e_address
WHERE s2.upc IN ('075172039394', '075172071622', ....)
```

This will return results in a slightly different "shape" so you will also need some changes to your client code.

Comment: I can't use an IN statement because I also have an export(csv) feature that needs to list the results horizontally for each upc.  I don't want to just determine what stores contain any upc, but also what upcs are in that store?

Comment: @user1184169: Whether the results are output horizontally or vertically shouldn't affect how you get the data from the database. Try to separate your data layer from your presentation layer.

Comment: @user1184169: If you really want to continue with the approach you are currently using, you should check your indexes as ypercube wrote. Please also post the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT...` for your query.

Comment: Thanks Mark made some changes to my question, please take a look if you get a chance.